# How to downgrade Kotlin version

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I've build a complete empty Project and I got this error:

> e: This version (1.0.0-alpha13) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.4.30 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.4.32 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

What can I do? (Sorry for this dumb question, but I'm complete new to Kotlin)

Thanks, Boothosh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can go to `Plugins` in the IDE settings and uninstall the Kotlin one there, and do Install From Disk (under the gear icon) and use one of these: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6954-kotlin/versions - you'd probably need to update your gradle files too (I haven't done any of this before so I can't tell you if it works or if you'll run into problems)

Why not just use a newer version of Compose though? [They're up to beta 6 now](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-compiler#1.0.0-beta06) - I can't even see an alpha 13 listed! Seems like a better idea all round, unless there's a really specific reason you need that version you're using?

Comment: I think I'll install the newer beta version, no there is no reason for using the old one... I've downloaded the standard package... How can I install the Beta of Compose?

Comment: I haven't used it, but just follow the setup guide? https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup#add-compose If you were already using it it's probably just a case of changing the version numbers in the compose dependencies, but there might be some new stuff / removed stuff. The dependencies there are beta01, so you'd probably want to change them to beta06, but make sure the non-compose libraries (the ``activity`` and ``lifecycle`` ones) are compatible. Probably fine but some releases rely on functionality introduced specific versions - this is a beta in development after all!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/lifecycle#lifecycle-viewmodel-compose-1.0.0-alpha04 and https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/activity#version_130_2 are the most recent ``compose`` libraries for those two, you probably just want to use those (but if there are problems that's probably where you should look). I know this is a bit vague but I haven't set it up myself so I don't have any personal experience, sorry!