# Downgrading Kotlin from 1.7.20 to 1.6.10 in android studio to support compose 1.1.1

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Android Studio Dolphin is configured with Kotlin 1.7.20, and to support Compose 1.1.1, we need Kotlin 1.6.10. After exhausting all of the options in Android Studio, I was unable to find a way to downgrade the Kotlin version.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade Kotlin version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67524034/how-to-downgrade-kotlin-version)

Comment: I have installed Kotlin 1.6.10 through disk and In Plugin section I did not find any option to disable Kotlin 1.7.20.

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use an updated version of Jetpack Compose. The current stable version is 1.3.2 and it is compatible with Kotlin version 1.7.20. If you use an outdated version of Jetpack Compose you will not benefit from the new features and fixes. See [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin) for compatibility.